# How to Add a CheckBox in Toolbar with custom background - android

Tags: android, checkbox

Hi i'm new in android and here 
i want to Have a CheckBox in my Toolbar with a custom background
my use case is : i want to add current post(in my activity) to favorites list by a checkbox in toolbar
and i wanna use a star(on/off) icon.

i tried this but the checkBox is null

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item android:id="@+id/shwo_menu_download_mp3"
    android:title="@string/download_mp3"
    app:showAsAction="never"/>
<item android:id="@+id/show_menu_add_to_fav"
    android:checked="true"
    android:enabled="true"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    />
<item android:id="@+id/show_menu_setting"
    android:title="@string/show_menu_setting"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
```

and my Activity:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_speech);
    initCheckBox();
    ...
}

CheckBox checkBoxFav;

private void initCheckBox() {
    checkBoxFav = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.show_menu_add_to_fav);

    checkBoxFav.setText("some Text");
}
```

Comment: [This](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/pro-tip-use-a-custom-layout-to-badge-androids-action-bar-menu-items/) shows how to add custom menu items & handle their clicks.

Answer (score 1):

with toolbar you can do this

```
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
View view= getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.view_, null);
Checkbox chbox = view.findViewById(..);
//chbox.do what u want with it
toolbar.addView(logo);
```

the view layout contains a checkbox and design it as you wish

Answer (score 0):

You have to follow these steps:
1. Create a toolbar and add it to your activity. I'm not going to explain that since there are a ton of tutorials on the matter.
2. Create a menu with a checkbox widget in it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_star"
        android:checkable="true"
        app:actionViewClass="android.widget.CheckBox"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="@string/favorite" />

</menu>
```

3. Add the set of icons in the drawable folder. One icon for the unchecked state and one icon for the checked state.
4. Create a resource file and name it whatever you want (In this example the name is `star.xml`), add it to the drawable folder and insert the following code in it:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
       <item
           android:state_checked="true"
           android:drawable="@drawable/star_black"
           />
       <item
           android:state_selected="true"
           android:drawable="@drawable/star_black"
           />
       <item
           android:state_checked="false"
           android:drawable="@drawable/star_border_black"
           />
      <item
           android:drawable="@drawable/star_border_black"
           />
   </selector>
   ```
5. create an `onCreateOptionsMenu` method in your activity and insert the following code. The icon of the checkbox will change automatically after getting checked or unchecked.

   ```
   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
       MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
       menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu,menu);
       CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)menu.findItem(R.id.menu_star).getActionView();
       checkBox.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.star);//set the icon to star.xml


       checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
           @Override
           public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
               //set the action of the checkbox
       }
       });



       return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
   }
   ```

Comment: Is there a way to set the action of the checkbox in onOptionsItemSelected() rather than setOnCheckedChangeListener()? I ask because I already have other menu items in my onOptionsItemSelected() and adding my checkbox to the switch statement would make my code cleaner. But for now I'm using this method you described because it's the only thing I've found to work.